# Remove array1 value which dosnt exist in array2 in php associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have five associative arrays in PHP which contain data from the database.

Here is an example of array 1 :

```
Array1
   (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [status] => 0
        [user] => 86
        [project] => 0
        [project1] => 0
        [project2] => 0
        [project3] => 0
        [project4] => 0
        [project5] => 0
        [project6] => 0
        [email] => info@mail.com
        [day] => 06/30/2013

    )
     [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [status] => 0
        [user] => 86
        [project] => 0
        [project1] => 0
        [project2] => 0
        [project3] => 0
        [project4] => 0
        [project5] => 0
        [project6] => 0
        [email] => infox@mail.com
        [day] => 06/30/2013

    )
)
```

Now here is array 2

```
   Array
     (
      [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [status] => 0
            [user] => 86
            [project] => 0
            [task] => 36
            [email] => info@mail.com
            [day] => 06/30/2013

        )
           )
```

I want to apply filter on my first array from `array2` to show only this after applying filter in result array

```
  result
      (
     [0] => Array
           (
     [id] => 2
    [status] => 0
    [user] => 86
    [project] => 0
    [project1] => 0
    [project2] => 0
    [project3] => 0
    [project4] => 0
    [project5] => 0
    [project6] => 0
    [email] => info@mail.com
    [day] => 06/30/2013

)
   )
```

Comment: change your query to add `join` keyword

Comment: cant join got so many table coming so many data set so best solution is get all different data in different array then apply filter

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use :

```
array_merge($array1,$array2);
```